# An image in a DIV and parameter height in %

Tags: image, html, height

I have a little problem with height :

First this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="photo" div name="photo" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 74%; height: 74%; left: 25%; top: 10">
<center><img id="grandeimg" img name="grandeimg" src="../../fonds/black.gif" img style="display:none; height:80%" onmouseover="this.style.display='none'"/></center>
</div>

<div align="left" style="position: absolute; width: 66%; height: 15%; left: 30%; top: 79%" >
<img alt="DSC_6844.JPG" src="DSC_6844_thumb.jpg" onmouseover="getElementById('grandeimg').src='DSC_6844.JPG';getElementById('grandeimg').style.display='block'" onmouseout="getElementById('grandeimg').src='../../fonds/black.gif';getElementById('grandeimg').style.display='none';"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For works, I use two images (one in full size DSC_6844 and other in small size DSC_6844_thumb.
When mouse on over the small picture, full picture is displayed, else full picture is not displayed.
In all version of Internet explorer before IE10, that's works fine (works fine with Firefox and other).

My problem is only on IE10.
The problem is on the img id="grandeimg", with the parameter height=80%
If I replace height=80% by width=80% or by height=500 the image is resized successfully.
But if I want resize image in height with % that doesn't work.

I am not an expert with html, I don't know css, I use only small html.

Can you test this little code (with the good name of two images at you, placed in the same directory that the html file) ?

Have you a solution ?

It is neccessary for me to resize image placed in the DIV by % because I use lanscape and portrait
picture.

Thnaks in advance for your answer and solution (please detailled solution or an example because I am not an expert of HTML).

Comment: Try adding `style="height:80%;` to your `<img>`

Comment: Sorry, I have write an error on height=80%, your are rigth the good usage is height:80%. I have change the example code but the problem is the same : height in % not works, only works height in pixels or width in pixels and width in %. My problem is not solved, is for height in %

Comment: Is there a reason you have "img" between each attribute in your `<img>`?

Comment: No reason, Have you a new line to propose ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand ? But (precision) if I put my img line over the DIV tag the height in % works fine, height in % only not works in hte DIV tag ????